# Handling format problems in textBox

Tags: c#

my task is that, ask the user to write a number in a textbox between 1 and 5. I have to handle the bad cases, like the user write a wrong number or write character instead number and this have to run as long as the program get a correct number. This is what I have right now.

```
        int right_number = int.Parse(number.Text); 
        try
        {
            if (right_number > 5 || right_number < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Warning");
            }
        }
        catch (NotFiniteNumberException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Warning");
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Comment: What kind of UI do you implement? `WinForms`, `WPF`, something else?

Comment: You should use int.TryParse instead of int.Parse, and you definitely should not use exception catching as part of your execution logic

Comment: It is a Windows Forms App in visual studio 2019
Only five good input: 1,2,3,4,5
Bad input: -8,66,aaa, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        if (int.TryParse(number, out right_number))
        {
            if (right_number > 5 || right_number < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Warning");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Warning");
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to solve this is to use a [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) control with the following properties:

- `MinValue` = 1
- `MaxValue` = 5
- `Value` = (a good starting default)
- `DecimalPlaces` = 0
- `Increment` = 1

NumericUpDown doesn't accept non numeric input, or anything outside its ranges, so all those cases you are worried about just.. disappear. The user can also use up/down keys to adjust the value

Answer (score 0):

This would be the cleanest way to validate your input:

```
bool IsInputValid(string input, out string warningMessage)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(input, out var integerValue))
    {
        warningMessage = "input could not be parsed to an integer";
        return false;
    }

    if (integerValue < 1 || integerValue > 5)
    {
        warningMessage = "input is not between one and five";
        return false;
    }

    warningMessage = string.Empty;
    return true;
}
```

The calling code would look something like this:

```
void TextChanged(string newText)
{
    if (!IsInputValid(newText, out var warningMessage))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(warningMessage);
    }

    //handle valid input here
}
```